# Org-mode: Limit the number of tasks to which a tag can be applied

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I have an idea where I have something like a FOCUS tag that I can apply to tasks that need special attention.

However, I want to make it so that only 3 tasks can actually be tagged with FOCUS at a time. If I try to tag a fourth with FOCUS, I should just get an error. So in order to apply a FOCUS tag, the count of currently FOCUS-tagged tasks should be <3, otherwise I'll have to untag one.

Any idea on how to get started on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The following concept draft idea will comb through the `org-agenda-files` and gather all the tags that fall within ambit of regexp group 5 to `org-complex-heading-regexp`, and then search through that list to find out how many matches of a particular tag.  The original poster may wish to perform a similar test when assigning a particular tag.

**USAGE**:  `(stop-or-go "NAME_OF_TAG")`

```lisp
(require 'cl) ;; for loop
(require 'org)
(require 'org-agenda)

(defun how-many-tags (tag)
"Tag must be a string without any colons."
  (let ((tag-list
          (loop for file in (org-agenda-files nil 'ifmode)
            append
            (let (result)
              (org-check-agenda-file file)
              (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
                (save-excursion
                  (goto-char (point-max))
                  (while (re-search-backward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t)
                    (push (match-string-no-properties 5) result)))
                result)))))
    (length
      (delq nil
        (mapcar
          (lambda (x) (when (and x (string-match (concat ":" tag ":") x)) x))
          tag-list)))))

(defun stop-or-go (tag)
"The default hard-coded count is 3.  Tag must be a string without any colons."
  (let ((count (how-many-tags tag)))
    (if (>= count 3)
      (message "STOP!:  %s" count)
      (message "GO!:  %S" count))))
```

Comment: The concept code works like a charm, and is very likely on the right path. The trouble I'm having now is finding a way to hook this into org's tag system.

Comment: When I use `C-c C-q` for `org-set-tags-command`, it tags the task and then runs the `org-after-tags-change-hook`. If I use `org-toggle-tag` or `org-set-tags-at` in `stop-and-go` to check and remove FOCUS, and then hook that, it will cause an infinite loop (since they call `org-set-tags` internally, which runs the hook). Are there any tag modification commands which don't?

Comment: The function `org-set-tags` is somewhat lengthy and would require a couple of cups of coffee to digest.  I'll have a look at it over the weekend and give it some thought.

Comment: It looks like a potential location to hack `org-set-tags-command` is right after the comment that reads:  `;; Insert new tags at the correct column`.  I've never tried to add more than one tag, but it appears as though multiple tags are expressly contemplated.  Therefore, each tag *may* need to be tested using something akin to the concept code above -- e.g., transform the string of tags at that point from `":tag1:tag2:tag3:"` to a list `'("tag1" "tag2" "tag3")` and each element of the list would be tested using the concept code above.  If any element fails the test, then throw an error/stop!